# Simple Javascript loop query for a beginner

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events

Please I've been having this problem for 2 days now.. I cannot solve it.. I know it's something basic but I can't seem to solve it..

I need to query all friends from Facebook and I need to post just those who have gender==male.

I do it and it returns only one result.. while I have more than 50 male friends..

Help me

```
  FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,gender', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var divContainer=$('.facebook-friends');
        var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");
        var i=0;

        while (i<response.data.length && response.data[i].gender=='male'){
            testdiv.innerHTML +=  response.data[i].first_name + '<br/>' ;
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: can you include the value of response. if it returns one result no amount of looping is going to help you have more

Comment: No, it has to return more than 1, like 50... someone else told me this : while (i<response.data.length && response.data[i].gender=='male')

stops when either of two conditions applies

1. i not less than response.data.length
2. response.data[i].gender contains 'male'

It therefore stops at the first male entry and will only reach the end of the array if everyone in it is female.

You need to move the second condition to an if statement inside the loop to capture all male entries instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your loop condition.

What you're saying with that loop is: As long as the person exists and is male, continue the loop. So, whenever your loop hits a female friend, it will return false and stop looping.

I would also recommend that you use a `for` loop for this instead of a `while` loop, like so:

```
for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    if(response.data[i].gender == 'male'){
         testdiv.innerHTML += response.data[i].first_name + '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Zach Lesperance :)
You saved my skin for today :D)
Infinite thanks :)